# How do you get a partial derivative of a vector to another vector?

Tags: vector-calculus

I have a translation function between Cartesian and Polar coordinates:

```
xi[xPrime_] := {xPrime[[1]]*Cos[xPrime[[2]]], xPrime[[1]]*Sin[xPrime[[2]]]}
```

I now want to take the partial derivative of that with respect to both the radius and angle given as another set of coordinates.  I've tried:

```
transformationMatrix[xPrime_] = {D[xi[xPrime], {{xPrime}}]}
```

and

```
transformationMatrix[xPrime_] = {D[xi[xPrime], xPrime[[1]], xPrime[[2]]]}
```

without any luck.  There must be an elegant way to take the partial derivative of a vector against another vector and get the transformation matrix.  How do you do this?

Comment: `xi[{x_, y_}] := {x Cos[y], x Sin[y]}`, then `D[xi[{x, y}], {{x, y}}]` computes gradient.

Comment: Thank you.  It works, but why am I unable to use pure vectors to represent that? **xi[v] := {v[[1]] Cos[v[[2]]],
  v[[1]] Sin[v[[2]]]};
f[v] = D[xi[v], {v}]**  That should be the same thing, only with arrays instead of individual components.

Comment: You can add `_List`: `xi[v_List] := {v[[1]] Cos[v[[2]]], v[[1]] Sin[v[[2]]]}`, `f[v_List] := D[xi[v], {v}]`, so `f[{a, b}]` gives `{{Cos[b], -a Sin[b]}, {Sin[b], a Cos[b]}}`.

Comment: More general: `ff[v_List] := Transpose[{Derivative[{1, 0}][xi][v], Derivative[{0, 1}][xi][v]}]`. Now you can use `ff[{a, b}]` or numerically `ff[{1,2}]`.